# Is there a preprocessor macro in CUDA that tells whether we are compiling device code?

Tags: c++, cuda, c-preprocessor

I'd like to define a pointer type that is shared between device and host code and internally stores the device and host pointer to the shared memory. I want it to determine at compile time, which pointer to actually return:

```
#define F inline __host__ __device__

class SharedMemory;
/**
 * 
 * Can only be set by allocating shared memory.
 */
template<typename T>
class SharedMemoryPtr {
public:
    SharedMemoryPtr() : hptr(0), dptr(0) {}

    //F ~ SharedMemoryPtr() {cudaFreeHost(hptr);} // Should be freed explicitly (?)

    // TODO: Don't allow copying/overwriting (at least not without freeing memory...)

    F T& operator() () {
#ifdef __CUDACC__
        return *dptr;
#else
        return *hptr;
#endif
    };

    F T* operator-> () {
#ifdef __CUDACC__
        return dptr;
#else
        return hptr;
#endif
    };

    F T& operator * () {
#ifdef __CUDACC__
        return *dptr;
#else
        return *hptr;
#endif
    };

    F T& operator[] (__int64 i) const {
#ifdef __CUDACC__
        return *(dptr + i);
#else
        return *(hptr + i);
#endif
    };

    friend SharedMemory;

    // TODO: Make obsolete (possible?)

    T * getHptr() {return hptr;} 
    T * getDptr() {return dptr;}

private:

    T *hptr, *dptr;
};

class SharedMemory {
public:
    template<typename T>
    static SharedMemoryPtr<T> allocate(int count = 1) {
        assert(count > 0);

        SharedMemoryPtr<T> sptr;

        cutilSafeCall(
            cudaHostAlloc(&sptr.hptr, sizeof(T) * count, cudaHostAllocMapped));
        assert(sptr.hptr);
        cutilSafeCall(
            cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&sptr.dptr, sptr.hptr, 0));
        assert(sptr.dptr);

        return sptr;
    }
};
```

This works fine as long as I use these pointers in code that is either in a cpp file (where `__CUDACC__` is never defined) or a .h file (where `__CUDACC__` is only defined if the function is used by some function in a cu file). However in a `__host__` function *in a .cu file*, I get the `devptr`. Obviously, .cu files are processed exclusively by nvcc. Is there some other preprocessor macro that is defined ONLY for `__global__` and `__device__` functions, not just everything nvcc happens to process? Or do I need to separate my code?

Comment: I guess I could also live with having my own macro, which is defined at the start of every cu file and which I can selevtively undefine if necessary...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__CUDA_ARCH__` is actual only for device code. You can specify device code behavior with it. 
This macro actually get compute capability of device code (like 200 for 2.0.)